# Why can't I use the whole char [] in while?

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, char

In Python, I can do:

```
str = "abcd"
while(str):
    print str
```

Although it's not very useful (iterating over the **elements** in the string is usually what's needed), the fact that it's possible makes me wonder why the equivalent in C is not, So:

```
char str[] = "abcd"
while(str[])
{
    do stuff
}
```

When I try to compile:

```
isblank.c:11:13: error: expected expression
        while (str[])
                   ^
1 error generated.
```

And I am forced to add the index of the string in the expression, therefore forcing it to iterate over the elements of the string.

Why so?

Comment: What are you struggeling with, `while(str)` or `while(str[])`? You seem to refer to both.

Comment: Please update your question with your actual copy-and-pasted code. You showed us code with `while(str)`, but the error message says you have `while (str[])`. You're getting an error message because `str[]` is not a syntactically valid expression. You *can* legally write `while (str)`, but it's not useful; it's always true, because an array name decays to a pointer to its first element in this context, and the resulting pointer is always non-null, which is what `while (str)` tests.

Comment: http://ideone.com/cyF6i2 `while(str)` does work, not really useful though.

Comment: Instead of asking "Why can't I use the whole char [] in while?", ask yourself (or others): I can do this in python. What's the equivalent code in C (or C++)?

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
char str[] = "abcd"
while(str)
{
    do stuff
}
```

is perfectly legal once you add a semicolon to the declaration of `str` and replace `do stuff` by actual code. It's also useless. `str` is an array expression, so it decays to a pointer to the array's first element in most contexts, including this one. When used as a condition, `if (pointer)` is equivalent to `if (pointer != NULL)`. So the loop continues to execute as long as the address of the array object `str` is not null -- i.e, forever. If you want an infinite loop, just write `while (1)` or `for (;;)`.

But your code didn't use `while (str)`; it used `while (str[])`, which produced this error:

```
isblank.c:11:13: error: expected expression
        while (str[])
                   ^
1 error generated.
```

The compiler complained simply because `str[]` is not a syntactically valid expression.

Your Python code:

```
str = "abcd"
while(str):
    print str
```

is an infinite loop that repeatedly prints `abcd`. The C equivalent is quite similar:

```
char str[] = "abcd";
while (str) {
    puts(str);
}
```

The evaluation of the condition is defined differently (C's `if` tests whether the pointer is non-NULL, while Python's `if` tests whether the string is non-empty), but in both cases it's always true, resulting in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Both snippet you are showing is doing same job (producing an infinite loop) except that, in python `str` is a reference to object `abcd`. This reference can be changed to another object. In C, `str` is an array and it is non modifiable lvalue.

Comment: Without the const qualifier, `str` is actually modifiable.

Comment: @inetknght; Interesting! I would like to know how?

Comment: so post a new question?

Comment: @inetknght; I am a smart guy! You can discuss it here in comments.

Comment: Yes but then only you benefit. The whole point of stackoverflow is to ask new questions instead of discussing new questions in comments

Comment: @inetknght; Do not worry I will ask question once I will convinced and then you can answer.

Comment: `/* gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Werror=all test.c || also need to #include <stdio.h> and <string.h> */ int main() { char a[] = "abcd"; for ( size_t n = strlen(a); n; --n ) { a[n-1] += 10; } printf("%s\n", a); return 0; }`

Comment: @inetknght; What I mean to say by *str is an array and it is non modifiable* is an array can't be a left operand of assignment operator or it can't be an operand of unary `--/++`. What you are showing me is modifying the elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Because the python has much smarter type recognition as it is higher level language with a lot of type information support.

While the array in the C is just a set of values in memory, in the python each object is actually containing more information about itself.

For instance if you take the string, it will define its iterator as well as its beginning and end of range operation. This is how the python knows when the object is starting ending etc.

In C however when you are asking for the array of data of a type char array you are getting exactly this. C is not even going to store the size of the array for you, so it is possible to access the 6th element of the 5 elements array. It will compile because it is correct C, but may explode in runtime. Having said that, if you would like to iterate through the array of chars the default behaviour is not assumed by C. Probably because of when and how it was designed, therefore you must specify to it how to access elements. Compiler can't tell whether you want to access them in order, in reverse order, every second etc. But because of lances of those assumptions, the memory usage of the array of chars will be always more efficient then in python.

Comment: I think you're assuming that the Python code iterates over the characters of the string. It doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this in C is:

```
char *str = "abcd";
for (; *str; str++)
{
    printf("Character is %c\n", *str);
}
```

Complete example:
http://ideone.com/AaEGgH

Comment: That's not what the Python code does. The Python code is an infinite loop that repeatedly prints `abcd`. It doesn't iterate over the characters of the string.

Comment: Okay, well, if you really want an infinite loop in C, just use `while(true)`.  But that seems so trivial that I'm not sure why anyone would ask about it.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why I'm expected to know what Python code does for a question tagged with C but not with Python.

Comment: I'm not sure why either -- but somebody did. I didn't say you're *expected* to know what the Python code does. You didn't, now you do.